# Cookie doesn't get saved in ASP.NET WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api, webmethod

I'm trying to save a cookie in a WebMethod and retrieve it upon Page_Load. However the cookie doesn't get saved and it returns a null in the Page_Load event.

Here's my code:

**WebMethod**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LoginUser(string email, string pass)
{
    //more code

    var ecookie= new HttpCookie("ecookie");
    ecookie["name"] = "roger";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ecookie);
}
```

**Page_Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    if (response.Cookies["ecookie"]["name"] != null) //doesn't go inside this condition since it's null
    {
          string name = response.Cookies["ecookie"]["name"];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: give the expiry also

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["userdata"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

Comment: Is it necessary to have an expiry? I need to store an Authentication Token @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saving the cookie value by the key `userdata` and are then retrieving it by the key `ecookie`.

Assuming you want to store the cookie with key `ecookie`, your `WebMethod` should probably look like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LoginUser(string email, string pass)
{
    //more code

    var ecookie= new HttpCookie("ecookie");
    ecookie["name"] = "roger";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ecookie);
}
```

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. The code still doesnt work

Comment: Is the WebMethod running on the same host server as the Page_Load in which you're trying to retrieve it? Did you try setting the expiration date as suggested by others?